# Outlook 2013 shows "not supported calendar message.ics", but Gmail, Outlook 2007 are fine

Tags: php, outlook, icalendar

My PHP program generate a ics file, it works previously for most email clients, but I got an error for Outlook 2013, the filename of the ics file, named "not supported calendar message.ics", but when double click to open it shows the content correctly. I search the internet but cannot find any reason. Could anyone help in this situation?

Here is the generated ics example:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//MY COMPANY NAME//System iCal Generator//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20170314T180000Z
DTEND:20170314T210000Z
DTSTAMP:20170217T161443Z
ORGANIZER;CN=name of event here:mailto:email@demoemailaddress.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE:customer@demoemailaddress.com
SUMMARY:Test website for evet
DESCRIPTION:xyz
LOCATION:tbc
SEQUENCE:0
UID:ICAL_128_NTG47K1VYJ@www.companydomain.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What error in Outlook do you get?

Answer (score 1):

An old one, but I'll go ahead and answer since it came up in my searches.

I had some problems with the newer Outlook being very particular about whether or not it would accept my event without weird issues...**and a lot of it actually came down to proper line-endings**.  I had to make sure `\r\n` was used within the VCalendar code, but in PHP on Unix, I had to make sure that `\n` was used for the new lines in the actual e-mail.  Here is some code that I have working with the latest Outlook, which uses string arrays so that the line-endings of each section is explicit and obvious:

> Please note that this code does nothing to prevent header-injection.
>   Please use responsibly :)

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    //CONFIGURE HERE
    $fromName           = "John Doe";
    $fromEmail          = "john.doe@example.com";
    $toName             = "Your Name";
    $toEmail            = isset($_GET['to']) ? $_GET['to'] : 'yourname@example.com';
    $start              = new DateTime('2017-08-15 15:00');
    $end                = new DateTime('2017-08-15 16:00');
    $summary            = "Hello World Event";
    //END CONFIGURATION

    $uid                = "0123456789";
    $headers            = array();
    $boundary           = "_CAL_" . uniqid("B",true) . "_B_";
    $headers[]          = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $headers[]          = "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"".$boundary."\"";
    $headers[]          = "To: \"{$toName}\" <{$toEmail}>";
    $headers[]          = "From: \"{$fromName}\" <{$fromEmail}>";

    $calendarLines      = array(
        "BEGIN:VCALENDAR",
        "METHOD:REQUEST",
        "PRODID:-//PHP//MeetingRequest//EN",
        "VERSION:2.0",
        "BEGIN:VEVENT",
        "ORGANIZER;CN={$fromName}:MAILTO:{$fromEmail}",
        "ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN={$toName}:MAILTO:{$toEmail}",
        "DESCRIPTION:{$summary}",
        "SUMMARY:{$summary}",
        "DTSTART:".$start->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'))->format('Ymd\THis\Z'),
        "DTEND:".$end->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'))->format('Ymd\THis\Z'),
        "UID:{$uid}",
        "CLASS:PUBLIC",
        "PRIORITY:5",
        "DTSTAMP:".gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z'),
        "TRANSP:OPAQUE",
        "STATUS:CONFIRMED",
        "SEQUENCE:0",
        "LOCATION:123 Any Street",
        "BEGIN:VALARM",
        "ACTION:DISPLAY",
        "DESCRIPTION:REMINDER",
        "TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M",
        "END:VALARM",
        "END:VEVENT",
        "END:VCALENDAR"
    );


    $calendarBase64     = base64_encode(implode("\r\n",$calendarLines));
    //ensure we don't have lines longer than 70 characters for older computers:
    $calendarResult     = wordwrap($calendarBase64,68,"\n",true);

    $emailLines = array(
        "--{$boundary}",
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso - 8859 - 1\"",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable",
        "",
        "<html><body>",
        "<h1>Hello World</h1>",
        "<p>This is a calendar event test</p>",
        "</body></html>",
        "",
        "--{$boundary}",
        "Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=\"utf - 8\"; method=REQUEST",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64",
        "",
        $calendarResult,
        "",
        "--{$boundary}--"
    );
    $emailContent   = implode("\n",$emailLines);

    $headersResult      = implode("\n",$headers);
    mail($toEmail, $summary, $emailContent, $headersResult );
    echo("<pre>".htmlentities($headersResult)."\n\n".htmlentities($emailContent)."</pre>");
    echo("<br /><br />");
    echo("<pre>".base64_decode($calendarResult)."</pre>");
```

Please feel free to add comments on applications/sites that this does or doesn't work with.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an appointment in Outlook and then save it using the .ics format. See [How To Save A Selected Appointment As Ics File In Outlook?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1525-outlook-save-one-appointment-as-ics.html) for more informaiton. Then you can open the saved file and compare its content with a generated programmatically one.

Answer (score 0):

Testing your icalendar feed with the icalendar validator at https://icalendar.org/validator.html it found the ATTENDEE line is longer than 75 characters, which is the maximum line size for an icalendar file. Perhaps that is why it is not working?

Comment: If so then why gmail is accepting long lines?